# Communicating variables between classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So I'm working on this OSX app with two windows. One window has an NS View with a custom view controller. I have global variables that contain important information which the window controller needs to tell the view controller. Unfortunately I can't alter these global variables. You see I have a couple of NSPopUpButtons that the user selects a couple of items from. I retrieve the indexs of these pop up boxes and assign these values to the global variables. Or at least I would like to but the global variables will not alter and I cannot read these changes from the NSView controller. What is the best way to get these variables across to the other class?

window controller .m:

```
#import "MenuController.h"


int gameOn = 0; //global variable

int gameMode = 0; //global variable

int player1Type; //global variable

int player2Type; //global variable
```

... selected item assigned to globals

```
-(IBAction) vsGameOpener: (id) sender
{
    player1Type = [player1Select indexOfSelectedItem];
    player2Type = [player2Select indexOfSelectedItem];
    gameMode = 1;
    [self unhideWindows];

}
```

window controller .h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "gameView.h"

extern int gameOn; //variable managing if the game is running or not

extern int gameMode; //variable managing what game mode it is: 0:menu, 1: VS, 2: practice

extern int player1Type; //variable for storing selected player 1 character

extern int player2Type; //variable for storing selected player 2 character
```

finally the view controller (gameView.m):

```
#import "gameView.h"

#import "MenuController.h"

extern int gameMode; //global variable

extern int gameOn; //global variable

extern int player1Type; //global variable

extern int player2Type; //global variable
```

Comment: If you actually have global variables, they should be accessible from anywhere. However, this would be very bad practice. You'll probably need to go through properties of one of the two classes, though it depends oa lot on how those two classes are linked. Please share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: added code to the question

Comment: Just to clarify, I can access the global variables from both classes but they are set to the numbers they are initialized with, I can't change them, not even from the class they are initialized in.

Comment: I don't know why your code is not working, but using global variables is (generally speaking) not a good idea. If you need to transfer data from one controller to a second controller there are a variety of techniques that can be employed. For example you could add a delegate protocol and set the second controller as a delegate of the first, which would call it any time a value was selected.

Comment: Could you expand on that solution please

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it turns out the globals were working fine. The issue I had was that the initializer for the nsview ran before the global values had been changed meaning that I now have to reinitialize the nsview when the window containing it shows itself. (It starts off hidden)